# Difference between に変わりない and と変わりない

Tags: particle-に, particle-と

Is there a difference between に変わりない and と変わりない, because I think I see/hear both?

> 外観は普通のタコと変わりない。

> 今日もいつもと変わりない一日でした。

> すべては以前と変りなかった

> あなたが彼の跡取り息子の母親であることには変わりないんだから

> 世界中人情に変わりは無い

> しかしありがたいに変わりは無い

---

Edit: the original post contained several typos and seemed to be about と変わらない and に変わらない, but it was meant to be about 変わりない.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

と as in Xと変わり(は)ない is the same と as in ～と比べる, ～と違う, ～と似ている, ～と同じ, ～と並ぶ. It marks the thing you compare something with. When you say Xと変わりない, you are comparing something *with X*. It means "(something) is no different from X".

に as in Xに変わり(は)ない is an abstract place marker. This に is the same に as in 私には夢がない, その理論に欠点はない, etc. When you say Xに変わりない, you are talking about the (possible) change of one thing, X (e.g., the significance of a fact, the meaning of a word). Thus, Xに変わりない means "X stays the same", "X still holds true", "X is always how it is", etc.

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference.

と変わらない means what you think it means. Something is no different from something else.

に変わらない is a variant of に変わり（は）ない or に違い（は）ない. It would say a less common one. These expressions are used to say something remains the same or some statement remains true despite a difference in appearance or despite the circumstances. Often times a noun clause comes before に as in your first example.

> あなたが彼の跡取り息子の母親であることには変わりないんだから。
> It remains true that you are the mother of the heir to his business.

こと is omitted in your last example.

> しかしありがたい（こと）に変わりは無い。
> I am equally grateful.
> (*lit.* There is no difference in that I am grateful.)

---

[Edit]

と変わりない means the same as と変わり（が／は）ない or と違い（が／は）ない. The function of と remains the same as と変わらない or と違わない. It's just using a noun instead of a verb.

Comment: I just realized I made a dumb and nontrivial mistake. I meant to ask about に変わりない and と変わりない, but typoed in the title and the first line while giving examples with 変わりない. Your answer is still very helpful nonetheless since it clarifies the difference between と変わらない and に変わらない. Would you mind adding a couple lines on と変わりない?

Answer (score -1):

I think there is a difference in nuance. As in [naruto's answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/93822/50904), it's a matter of saying "similar with" (と変わりない, lit. has no difference with) vs. saying "similar to" (に変わりない, lit. has no difference to).

＊私は兄**と**変わりない。
*Watashi wa ani-to kawarinai.* There is no difference between me and my brother, i.e. I am nothing lesser of him.

＊私は兄**に**変わりない。
*Watashi wa ani-ni kawarinai.* I don't make a difference to brother. This could be in both a positive or negative sense; i.e. whether it's me or my father going with him, my brother trusts us both so it won't matter, **OR** my brother is indifferent to whether or not I will be there.

Comment: How does that apply to the example sentences in the question? E.g. 

    世界中人情に変わりは無い

Comment: Hmm.. perhaps "it's doesn't matter to" might be a more flexible English translation. It's really the same idea. [It] doesn't matter/make a difference to the people around the world. に  can both act as "an abstract place marker", but can also have this sense of "according to [subject]" which fits OP's examples.